# How do I resolve collection error with my controller in ASP.NET MVC in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.  Here are the BikeController and Bike Model.  When I run the program the error is "Cannot initialize type 'MvcApplication3.Models.Bike' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'."  The error is on the line `bikes = new Bike {` but when I placed `using System.Collections.IEnumerable;`in the Bike Model, it said "A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' is a type not a namespace."  Thanks in advance.

Bike Controller:

```
using MvcApplication3.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class BikeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Bike/

        Bike bikes;

        public BikeController()
        {
            bikes = new Bike {
                new Bike(),
                new Bike { Manufacturer = "Nishiki", Gears = 5, Frame = "Road" }
            };
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(this.bikes);
        }

        private ActionResult View(Func<object> func)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(Bike b)
        {
            return View(b);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Bike/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Bike/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bike Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class Bike
    {

        public int BikeID { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public int Gears { get; set; }
        public string Frame { get; set; }

        static protected int bikeCount;

        public Bike()
        {
            this.Manufacturer = "Schwinn";
            this.Gears = 10;
            this.Frame = "Mountain";
            this.BikeID = bikeCount;
            bikeCount++;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize controller like this :

```
    public class BikeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Bike/

        List<Bike> bikes;

        public BikeController()
        {
           bikes = new List<Bike>() {
               new Bike(),
               new Bike { Manufacturer = "Nishiki", Gears = 5, Frame = "Road" }
           };
        }

        ...
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  May I ask you another question?  How should my return statement read here:  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(bike[id]);
        }

Comment: try : return View(bikes.Where(b => b.BikeID == id).first());

Comment: It said 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.Bike>' does not contain a definition for 'first' and no extension method 'first' accepting a first argument of type Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.Bike>' does not contain a definition for 'first' and no extension method 'first' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.Bike>' could be found.

Comment: Ho, its First() sorry

Comment: It said: The type or namespace name 'Bikes' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcApplication3.Models'.

Comment: And its true :) nowhere i see Bikes, just bikes (the list) or Bike (the class)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37852/discussion-between-grafica-and-pascalz)

Comment: Later, i come back in 1h

Comment: In View, I had @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.Bikes> so I changed it to Bike without an 's' & it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable bikes as a list

```
List<Bike> bikes;
```

and then instantiate it

```
bikes = new List<Bike>() {
                             new Bike(),
                             new Bike() { ... },
                             ...
                         };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use List<> for bikes.